# 1 sentence, 3 tenses, 1 infinitive, 2 voices, 1 giant headache

Tags: tenses, past-tense, future-in-past

Help me parse this sentence. I feel like it is not correct, but I cannot figure out a different way to express the thought.

> Therefore, it is my sincere hope to hear that [he] was accepted to the Masters of Public Affairs program.

I know we can change tenses if the timing changes and I know there is future perfect to describe future acts that have been completed. However, *was accepted* is simple past tense in passive voice and thus shouldn't be used to describe something that will have happened. However, passive future perfect is doesn't make sense either because, relative to the time that I would hear this, he would have already been accepted and thus it's not describing a future act.

The way I see it, there are three verbs with three tenses describing three acts in three times.

- is - present tense - present time
- to hear - infinitive form - future
- was accepted - past simple - future relative to verb one, past relative to verb two.

I realize that I switch voices midway through, that is for stylistic purposes. The issue I'm having doesn't go away if I change it to active voice.

Is the sentence grammatically correct, or is there a different, more proper, way to say it?

Comment: *to hear - infinitive form – future* Infinitives have no tense but “to hope” always refers to a future event – this gives the **sense**, rather than the **tense**, of the future. ++ Thus your **current** hope is that (i) something **in the past** has happened to him, and (ii) if it has, you will be informed of this.  “*{to hear that [he] was accepted to the Masters of Public Affairs program."}* describes or defines your hope and this is not bound by the tense of the main clause: *He hopes that it **is/was/will be** cheap/a cat* are all valid descriptions of what is hoped.

Comment: I'm very confused. There's nothing wrong with any of these: *Therefore, it is my sincere hope to hear that he **[is / was / will be / will have been]** accepted …*

Comment: My apologies: I was giving a general "that" clause as an example.